# Visual studio code terminal is showing some messages I don't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, fetch

Don't know what happened to my terminal, whenever I use fetch method in my react code, my code doesn't run and the error message shows up in the terminal.

> Sending uncompressed crash reports is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Electron. Set { compress: true } to opt-in to the new behavior. Crash reports will be uploaded gzipped, which most crash reporting servers support.

Comment: Did you not search that error message?

Comment: Have you looked at the crash report